# Cómo filtrar por fechas DATAVIEWGRID y DATETIMEPICKER?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

Buen día raza, fijense que tengo un detalle que me esta volviendo loco desde hace algunos días, sucede que necesito filtrar por un rango de fechas 01/02/2020 - 01/04/2020 la cual el codigo que estoy manejando en otros forms conectado a mi base de datos por mysql  funciona correctamente, pero en un form en especifico no me funciona.

Sucede que sí filtra, pero solo filtra por día, hace caso omiso al mes y al año, ya intente cambiar los formatos y aun asi tengo el mismo problema, vuelvo a reiterar que en otros formularios de reporte si puedo filtrar correctamente, solo es un caso en particular.

El formato que necesito filtrar es fecha y hora como la siguiente 27/04/2021 01:27:40 p. m. dejo el codigo para mayor referencia y ver que esta pasando.

```
':::Procedimiento para filtras en MySQL
    Dim Con2 As New MySqlConnection("server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;user=root;password=root;database=;port=3306")
    Sub Filtro_MySQL(ByVal Sql As String, ByVal Tabla As DataGridView)
        ':::Creamos nuestro objeto MySQLDataAdapte, el cual recibe dos parametros
        ':::La conexion y la consulta SQL
        Dim Da As New MySqlDataAdapter(Sql, Con2)
        ':::Creamos nuestro DataTable para almacenar el resultado
        Dim Dt As New DataTable
        ':::Llenamos nuestro DataTable con el resultado de la consulta
        Da.Fill(Dt)
        ':::Asignamos a nuestro DataGridView el DataTable para mostrar los registros
        Tabla.DataSource = Dt
        ':::Damos color a las filas y formato a la columna hora
        Tabla.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        Tabla.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White


    End Sub
```

y aca los filtros

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ':::Damos el formato requerido por la base de datos a cada
        ':::Control DateTimePicker 27/04/2021 01:27:40 p. m.
        Dim FechaInicio As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyy")
        Dim FechaFinal As String = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyy")
       

        ':::Mediante la funcion Between de SQL obtenemos los valores
        ':::Que esten entre el rango de las fechas de inicio y fin
        Dim Sql As String = "select * from tabla.pagos where fecha between '" & FechaInicio & "' and '" & FechaFinal & "'"

        ' Dim Sql As String = "Select A.id ID, A.cliente CLIENTE, A.empresa EMPRESA , A.gerencia GERENCIA, A.medios MEDIOS, b.idtmk, b.fecha, b.monto_pago, b.metodopago, b.observaciones, b.asesor From tabla.perfiles A RIGHT JOIN tabla.pagos b On A.id=b.idfolio where b.fecha between '" & FechaInicio & "' and '" & FechaFinal & "' and b.status='" & textstatus.Text & "'"
        ':::Llamamos el procedimiento que creamos en nuestro modulo para la base de datos SQLite
        ':::Y le pasamos los dos valores que requiere, el nombre del DataGridView y la consulta SQL
        Filtro_MySQL(Sql, DGVActivos)

    End Sub
```

Vuelvo a repetir que en otros formas sí me funcioan el código, este en especifico sí me filtra pero sólo toma los primeros valores de la fecha, quiere decir el día, pero no filtra el mes y año.